# Solving $e^{\sin x} + e^ {\cos x} = e + 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry, exponential-function

> How can we solve this equation?
>   $$e^{\sin x} + e^ {\cos x} = e + 1$$

I know that $x=0$ and $x=\pi/2$ are solutions, as well as their periods, and that $x$ has to be between $0$ and $\pi/2$, but I don't know how to prove there aren't any other solutions.

Comment: Are you sure it is supposed to be $e+1$ on the right hand side? Take a natural logarithm of both sides to start.

Comment: How does that help me? The logarithm isn't linear...

Comment: My bad, you are right, but this can be done by inspection. You need $sin(x)=1$ and $cos(x)=0$.

Comment: @Laars Helenius or vice versa and he has these roots. He needs to prove that there aren’t any others

Comment: Technically speaking if we are over $\mathbb{R}$ there are an infinite number of roots, $x=2\pi k$ and $x=2\pi k + \pi/2$.

Comment: @LaarsHelenius Asix did point that out in the initial question.

Comment: @LaarsHelenius  The OP clearly lists those roots.  The problem is to exclude any others.

Comment: Please note my updated comment.

Comment: I don't see a very pleasant way to do it.  One idea:  let $f(x)=e^{\sin x}+e^{\cos x}-e-1$ and note that it suffices to show that $f'(x)=0$ has only two solutions in $[0,2\pi]$.  That works out to showing that $\tan x = e^{\sin x- \cos x}$ has only two solutions in that interval which I believe is easier. (the solutions are just $\frac {\pi}4, \frac {5\pi}4$).

Comment: Try to prove that between the known solutions (between $0$ and $\pi/2$), there is only one extremum (maximum). Then, you can prove through convexity that the secant from one to the other solution lies entirely on the same side of the curve (with no extra intersections).

Comment: I proved it using the function $g(t)=e^t/t,$ which is decreasing for $0<t<1.$ If $f(x)=e^{\sin x}+e^{\cos x},$ then $f'(x)=\sin x \cos x (g(\sin x)-g(\cos x))$ and one can easily find regions of monotonicity of $f.$

Comment: @GeorgiiRiabov Nice! You should write an answer.

Comment: There are infinity many solutions, do you have an interval?

Comment: @bjcolby15: The logarithm does not distribute over addition, so your "first case" is nonsensical.

Comment: @Blue - you are correct...I fixed the comment so it made sense.

Comment: Whoops - make that *deleted.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested by @zhw, I'll place here a proof of the statement: the only real roots of the equation 
$$
e^{\sin x}+e^{\cos x}=e+1
$$
are $x=2\pi k,$ $x=\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi k,$ $k\in\mathbb{Z}.$

From $2\pi-$periodicity of $\sin$ and $\cos$ it is sufficient to show that the only roots from $[0,2\pi)$ are $x=0$ and $x=\frac{\pi}{2}.$ For $\frac{\pi}{2}<x<2\pi$ one of functions $\sin$ or $\cos$ is negative, hence in the sum $e^{\sin x}+e^{\cos x}$ one summand is $<1.$ The other is always $\leq e$ and the value $e+1$ can't be obtained.

It remains to consider $x\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}].$ Let $f(x)=e^{\sin x}+e^{\cos x},$ $0\leq x\leq \frac{\pi}{2}.$ Then for $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$
$$
f'(x)=\cos xe^{\sin x}-\sin xe^{\cos x}=\sin x\cos x\bigg(\frac{e^{\sin x}}{\sin x}-\frac{e^{\cos x}}{\cos x}\bigg)=\sin x\cos x (g(\sin x)-g(\cos x))
$$
where $g(t)=\frac{e^t}{t}.$ For $0<t<1$ the function $g$ is decreasing, as $g'(t)=\frac{e^t(t-1)}{t^2}.$ Then 
$$
f'(x)>0\Leftrightarrow g(\sin x)>g(\cos x)\Leftrightarrow \sin x<\cos x
$$
Function $f$ is strictly decreasing on $[0,\frac{\pi}{4}]$ and strictly increasing on $[\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2}].$ As $e+1=f(0)=f(\frac{\pi}{2}),$ for all $x\in(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ we have $f(x)<e+1.$